# T-SQL Error Messages in Visual Studio 2019 not showing anymore

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, ms-sql

I would like some suggestions if this could be fixed you I need to fix/re-install Visual Studio. 
The error messages were visible a few days ago. I am using Visual Studio for SQL queries for two weeks after I started studying MS-SQL but not showing errors now is really problematic.

Screenshot of my Visual Studio when error must be displayed in the lower pane:

[image: Screen-Shot of my Visual Studio when error must be displayed in the lower pane]

Comment: What exactly is your question? It doesn’t appear you have not selected the Error list tab.

Comment: The question is obvious, how to fix that if anyone knows.Error List tab shows only sometimes, what the error is. For example, I am creating a transaction and this fails, but Error List is empty despite  getting a warning "Query completed with errors"...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.